# Download different types using blob in angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, system

I already wrote code to save PDF files in Angular but when I try to save the jpg image format it not showing download option. Why?

```
downloadfile(type: string){

    let thefile = {};
    this.pservice.downloadfile(this.rundata.name, type)
        .subscribe(data => thefile = new Blob([data], { type: "application/octet-stream" }), //console.log(data),
                    error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
                    () => console.log('Completed file download.'));

    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(thefile);
    window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in **Blob constructor** and **MIME type** you are specifying. In your code, you are using "application/octet-stream" as the MIME type, which is a generic binary data type. This MIME type may not be recognized by the browser as a valid format for images, resulting in the download option not being displayed.

you should specify the correct MIME type for the image format you are downloading. For JPG images, the MIME type is "image/jpeg".

Please modify your code

```
downloadfile(type: string) {
  let thefile: Blob;
  this.pservice.downloadfile(this.rundata.name, type)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        thefile = new Blob([data], { type: "image/jpeg" });
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(thefile);
        window.open(url);
      },
      error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
      () => console.log('Completed file download.')
    );
}
```